# Difference between returning object literal vs raw values directly in this.setState? (React.JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, return, setstate

My goal is to change a `state` object through a `this.setState` method, but there's a thing that makes me confusing.

First, I created an object literal called `newCount`, gave a new `key: value` pair data and returned the `newCount`, but the browser doesn't increase the `count` value what I expected.

this is the code:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    var newCount = {
        count: prevState.count + 1
    } // It won't increase. Just keeps showing 1.
    return {
        newCount
    }
})
```

But when I try to return the values directly like this, it works:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
        count: prevState.count + 1
    } // It goes working. 
})
```

What's the difference between those 2 code blocks?

Comment: You are using [Shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) syntax in the first one. So, you are returning `{ "newCount": newCount }` or `{ newCount: { count: prevState.count + 1 } }`. You need to change it to `return newCount` to make it similar to the second one

Comment: @adiga I understood perfectly but I can't explain for recapping because my limited vocabulary :< Thank you for advice both of you guys <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first code sample creates a new field inside state called `newCount`:

```
return {
   newCount, // es6 shorthand - equals to `newCount: newCount`
}
```

The second example works correctly since you are updating the proper `count` field.

If you would like to make it work in both ways, just add a correct field name:

```
return {
   count: prevState.count + 1, // or `count: newCount.count`
}
```

More details about objects initializing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Comment: @adiga Of course, just focused too much on incorrect field initialization, thanks!

Comment: So, the reason that my ***first*** attempt isn't working is, I'm actually not re-assigning `newCount` as a value of `count` when I return it, right?

Comment: @sniffingdoggo Oh, your second one works fine, but the first one does not since you are not updating the proper field inside state. You are not interested on `newCount`, but on `count`, right?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the first one, lol. And no, I interest on `newCount`.